# cassandra snapshot without nodetool but by java api only

Tags: cassandra, snapshot, take

How to take cassandra snapshot without nodetool but  by java api only? I need to take snapshot of keyspace in cassandra by not using nodetool utility. I have to do it by java api
If any one know  how to do it kindly answer it . I have to implement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't take a snapshot using the thrift API, but you can take a snapshot using JMX, which is how the nodetool command works.  Look at the node tool source [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-1.1.0/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/NodeCmd.java), in particular look at the [handleSnapshot](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-1.1.0/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/NodeCmd.java#L905) method.