# Is there a way to use cassandra nodetool programatically?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

For example, how I can take snapshots programmatically and also restore them. Please help me if you have any solution or workaround it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cassandra snapshot without nodetool but by java api only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403292/cassandra-snapshot-without-nodetool-but-by-java-api-only)

Comment: @Rafael right now my use case is taking/restoring snapshots only, but I may need to run other nodetool commands pro-grammatically  in future.

Answer (score 2):

You could use cassandra's source code as a library (nodetool utility is part of that source code). There are classes called [NodeProbe](https://github.com/mariusae/cassandra/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/NodeProbe.java) and [Status](https://fossies.org/linux/misc/apache-cassandra-3.10-src.tar.gz/apache-cassandra-3.10-src/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/nodetool/Status.java) that you can use.

Comment: Can you provide some details about how to this exacly with some example

Comment: Once you add a dependency on cassandra's jar, here's how you can remove a node from your cluster: 
 new NodeProbe("ip-address-of-an-endpoint-in-cluster").removeNode("host-id-of-node-running-cassandra")

Once you have an instance of NodeProbe class, browse its methods to see what all you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Use JMX, I like [jmxsh](https://code.google.com/p/jmxsh/) for this kind of thing. You can call it from cron.

If you're looking for a more complete solution, OpsCenter does backup and restore (point and click). Check out Mani's [post](http://www.datastax.com/2015/03/datastax-opscenter-5-1-real-world-test-simulation-of-visual-backup-and-restore-services). I mention this since you have `datastax-enterprise` in the question. The backup service is disabled if you're running open source cassandra.

Here's some sample shell scripting I've used to change concurrent compactors, you can do something similar.

```
wget https://jmxsh.googlecode.com/files/jmxsh-R5.jar
wget https://jmxsh.googlecode.com/files/jmxsh
echo jmx_set -m org.apache.cassandra.db:type=CompactionManager CoreCompactorThreads 4 > changeCoreCompactors.sh
echo jmx_set -m org.apache.cassandra.db:type=CompactionManager MaximumCompactorThreads 4 > changeMaxCompactors.sh
java -jar jmxsh-R5.jar -h localhost -p 7199 -q changeCoreCompactors.sh 
java -jar jmxsh-R5.jar -h localhost -p 7199 -q changeMaxCompactors.sh
```

Comment: Thanks ! Can you guide me to any such 'JMXSH' existing code for this purpose. Any idea why Cassandra driver haven't provided such functionality(or I am wrong)?