# How can i run and return the cassandra nodetool command and its output

Tags: cassandra, cql, nodetool

How can i run and return the cassandra nodetool command and its output using Java. I checked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403292/cassandra-snapshot-without-nodetool-but-by-java-api-only) but there is no clarity about how to do it exactly.

Comment: What it's your use case? May be you can get out those info from JMX or run some commands through JMX.

Comment: i want to run any nodetool command in java and get the ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ShellTest {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException {
            // Get runtime
            java.lang.Runtime rt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
            // Start a new process: UNIX command ls
            java.lang.Process p = rt.exec("ccm node1 nodetool status");
            // You can or maybe should wait for the process to complete
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Process exited with code = " + p.exitValue());
            // Get process' output: its InputStream
            java.io.InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            // And print each line
            String s = null;
            while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            is.close();
        }
}
```